# .NET 4.0 Entity framework timeout expired

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, timeout

I'm developing an ASP.NET website using MVC3, .NET framework 4.0 and Entity Framework. When I run the application and perform a simple select to a SQL Server 2005 database I get the following error:

"A System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was thrown: "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."

This is the thing. I tried logging in and performing the same query from management studio and it worked. I developed a small console application using .NET framework 4.0 and entity framework performing the exact same query and it returned the information I needed. I even switched from using Entity framework to ADO.NET classes (SqlConnection and SqlCommand) and when executing the select from the SqlCommand instance I get the exact same error.

When I created the model using entity framework I was able to connect from the wizard to the database and it worked fine. I got all the classes created without any problems.

Please don't tell me the solution is to increase any timeout because the query is really small (20 records tops) and as I said before it worked fine when running it from a console application using the same technology and even the same code I place below.

This is the code giving me the problem:

```
MLIBEntities dbMLIB = new MLIBEntities();

var searchResults = (from s in dbMLIB.Sets
                     where s.setmap1.StartsWith(accountNumber)
                     select s);

return searchResults.ToList();
```

The exception is thrown when running searchResults.ToList();

This is my connection string being used by the entity classes. I'm sure it uses the connection string since I modified it with syntax errors and they were detected.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MLIBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MlibDBModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MlibDBModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.MlibDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=HERPADERP;Initial Catalog=MLIB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=200&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I'm guessing this must be a configuration problem somewhere in the MVC web application or I'm just missing something in the Web.config file. Have any of you had this problem? I know it's really weird.

Thank you for your help. I'm really out of ideas.

One last thing. I ran the SQL profiler and it seems like the query never makes it to the database server. Any ideas of why could this be happening?

Comment: Does it actually time out after 200 seconds?

Comment: Really, no relation to ASP.NET MVC 3.

Comment: SQL Server is local or on network?

Comment: Are you saying that some queries work but the searchResults one does not? Did you use the same connectionStrings section from your web/config file in your console application? What connection string did you use when you used ADO.NET core?

Comment: Ok, the request throws a timeout after about 10 seconds. the SQL Server is on a network but as I said, I started a profiler trace (from the same machine I'm running the application from) and the request never seems to get to the server.

Comment: I only have one query in the application. The one placed above. It doesn't work in the MVC application but it works perfectly in the console application. I use the exact same connectionString section from the web/config file in the app/config file of the console application. The connection string I used when I used the ADO.NET core is the one inside the one I placed here: Data Source=HERPADERP;Initial Catalog=MLIB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=200

Comment: At this point I think I'm about to start a new project from scratch and do it all over again. If that works I'll let you all know. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. It seems like the query was indeed returning a huge amount of records and it was causing a timeout when running it from the web application while it wasn't happening in the console application given its nature.

Thank you again!

Comment: The console application would retrieve the same amount of records at approximately the same time. It's not which application is querying the database, it's the database and/or the records.

Comment: you're right, there was something fishy there. I optimized the query and it fixed the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and another one also appeared later, not related to MSSQL. To solve first problem (running queries took too long), I changed `command.CommandTimeout` to use larger number (default is 30). Another problem that showed up was when I used scheduled task to run this application - after 20 minutes it would thrown error

> "Thread was being aborted"

After reviewing log errors, it came out that application pool also has it's timeout, and default value is 20 minutes.

Comment: Also in EF, you can set ObjectContext.CommandTimeout to extend the timeout if you want to be provider agnostic. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.commandtimeout.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This might appear as a timeout, but is possibly just a security issue.

My first instinct is that you're connecting using Windows authentication (Integrated Security=True) and the website is running under an account (Network Service?) that does not have a valid login for that server.

My second instinct is that the Sql Server is on a different machine, and there is a firewall issue.

Third instinct is that Sql Server isn't configured to accept network connections over TCPIP.  Run the Sql Server Configuration Manager and make sure it's listening.

Comment: But he was able to connect from ConsoleApp, so problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: @Tomas He connects from a console app under his user account.  ASP.NET runs under a different account, so you are incorrect.

Comment: You are totally correct. I realized that after writing comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I already had timeouts with MultipleActiveResultSets=True in the connection string, try to turn it off to see if it's the problem