# How to set SQL Server 2008 R2 remote transaction time out

Tags: transactions, sql-server-2008-r2, timeout

I have written a stored procedure which is executing from a c# windows from application. I am connecting to the server using an entity data model.

The problem is my stored procedure takes more than 4 minutes to execute and complete its process

BUT whenever I am executing it gives error

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

As I searched this is due to remote transaction time out because I am executing it from my c# code because when i am executing it from server it always complete with no error

PLS HELP ME..

Comment: How much time does it take when you run it directly on server?
can you share code snippet and sp?

Comment: Thanks for comment @Tauseef as i mentioned it takes almost 4 minutes

Comment: Is there any setting in MSSQL from which i set transaction timeout

Comment: it would be better if you could optimize the stored procedure, try following: convert the sub queries/inner queries to joins if possible.
remove unnecessary joins.
extending the time would not be a good idea.

Comment: I sort out All things but it is really taking too much time please suggest me what to do now

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following, you must finout these helpful

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190181(v=sql.105).aspx

[.NET 4.0 Entity framework timeout expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927298/net-4-0-entity-framework-timeout-expired)